# Datetime Parse Exact

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, datetime-format

I'm trying to change the dateformat from `"4/01/2013 0:00:00"` to `"01/4/2013 00:00:00"`.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(fromDate.ToString(), "m/dd/yy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/mm/yy HH:mm:ss");
```

However I get

> *"String was not recoginezed as a valid DateTime."*

Comment: If `fromDate` is already a string, why `ToString`? Is your issue parsing to date or getting a string from a date? What is the month and what the day here: `4/01` / `01/4`(you could choose better sample dates)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter More importantly, if fromDate is already a *date*, why go through all this trouble when you can just use ToString and a format to begin with?

Comment: Why so many downvotes? It is a pretty valid question.Sometimes I feel the community is prejudiced against "newbies".

Answer (score 5):

Your year part is `yy` but instead it should be `yyyy` since you are using 4-digit year. 
Additionally, lower case `m` stands for minutes, not months - which in case is upper case `M`. Your code should be like this:

```
string fromDate = "4/01/2013 0:00:00";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(fromDate, "M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string formattedDate = dt.ToString("dd/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

You are doing `fromDate.ToString()`, if `fromDate` is already a string you don't have to call `ToString` and if it is a date type, then you don't have to parse it, instead you can format it directly.